# copy all files recursively into a single folder (without recreating folders)

Tags: batch-file, directory, xcopy

With a batch (.bat), I want to copy all mp3 files that are in 1 subdirectory of D:\TEMP

```
D:\TEMP\\(anyfolder)\\(anyfile.mp3)
```

to

```
E:\MYFOLDER\
```

I tried with xcopy but

- I don't know how to tell "just recurse subfolders of D:\TEMP and not subsubfolders, subsubsubfolders, etc."
- When using xcopy, folders are created in the destination (in order to replicate source's folder tree), I don't want this : files should be copied in just 1 single folder.

Comment: Check this method, does not require any batch files or learning any DOS commands- http://www.pcworld.com/article/2105149/gather-similar-files-from-multiple-folders-and-copy-them-in-one-simple-step.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`for` command is your friend. Read `help for` and then try this in the command prompt

```
for /d %a in (*) do @echo %a
```

as you see, it follows all subfolders in the current directory.

thus,

```
for /d %a in (*) do @copy %a\*.mp3 e:\myfolder
```

will copy all your mp3 to the destination folder.